# How to decrease the file size upload limit?

Tags: uploads

How do I decrease my media file size upload limit from 20 MB to 500 KB? I actually tried to follow the solution used in [Decrease file size upload in Media](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70754/decrease-file-size-upload-in-media) but got a "undefined add_filter()" error. I inserted the code at the bottom of functions.php.

Using WP 3.5.1

What should I do? Thank you

Comment: Please add more info. Where do you put the code? In `functions.php`?

Comment: Yes in functions.php at the very bottom

Comment: the error indicates that you are not using the functions.php in your current theme directory, is that the case?

Comment: @birgire ah yes that is true... I pasted it in the original functions.php. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: the path should be like this: /wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/functions.php or better yet, change this code into a plugin, see more about it here https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Thanks! You reminded me of plugins! So dumb of me not to think of it in the first place. Found a plugin that sorta works... It'll do for now

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this questions depends on the level of access you have to your server. Shared hosts often limit the options you have. Your options are:

**1) Changing a [directive](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in your php.ini:** [Heres how to find it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17185370/8015265)

This will change the setting for **all** websites using php on this server. Many shared hosts don't allow this.

Find the line in that says `upload_max_filesize` and edit it to look like the following:

`upload_max_filesize = 500K`

**2.a) Setting an ini directive in the .htaccess file (if you use apache):**

In the .htaccess file in the WordPress root directory (where the `wp-config.php` file is) add the following on a new line:

`php_value upload_max_filesize 500K`

This will change the setting for that installation of WordPress only.

Be aware, many shared hosts will not allow this. Additionally this will only work if you are using PHP as an apache module and `AllowOverride` is set to "Options" or "All" [more info here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

**2.b) With a [.user.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) file:**

Much like .htaccess above, a `.user.ini` file is used to override directives at a directory level. This will only work if your server is using the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. So if you're on Azure App Service/IIS or something similar this is probably what you want.

Syntax is: `upload_max_filesize = 500K`

**3) Changing the directive in WordPress with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php):**

This should work on a shared host.

Add the following line to your `functions.php`:

`ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '500K' );`

This works by changing the setting every time this file is run. `functions.php` is run on every load when the theme is active so this effectively changes the limit when using your theme.

**Bonus: WordPress Multisite**

Navigate to Network Admin > Settings > Network Settings. You should see the setting close to the bottom of the page. However, the maximum limit you can set here is dictated by the other PHP settings outlined in the this answer.

Comment: `1) Changing a directive in your php.ini` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside of the `functions.php` file to in case or decrease the upload size. You can also increase the size by changing 2M to more.

```
@ini_set('upload_max_size', '500K');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '500K');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '300');
```

Comment: Making `post_max_size` that small will most likely mess other stuff up like the saving of menus and posts. The max `max_execution_time` wouldn't need to be changed for this question either. I wouldn't change `post_max_size` or `max_execution_time` unless there is a reason to.

Answer (score -1):

I am using the plugin [WP Image Size Limit](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-image-size-limit/). It works about 80% the way I like.

A couple of things I don't like:

1. In the Upload Media view still says 20 MB is the limit.
2. Looks like it does the size check AFTER the upload is done, instead of before. Seems inefficient to me.

Comment: plugins are rarely good answers..., this was unmaintained for a while

Answer (score -1):

**First Method**

You can add this in your functions.php file :

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '500K' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '500K');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '100' );
```

**Second Method**

Add this in your .htaccess file :

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500K
php_value post_max_size 500K
php_value max_execution_time 100
php_value max_input_time 100
```

**Thirs Method**

Add this in your php.ini file :

```
upload_max_filesize = 500K
post_max_size = 500K
max_execution_time = 100
```

Comment: Not sure why everyone thinks changing the `post_max_size` and `max_execution_time` setting are necessary. Making `post_max_size` so low will likely cause issues with menus/posts/pages saving, especially when using a menu builder plugin. The issue may not be evident immediately but as the site grows so does the risk of conflict.

Answer (score -2):

put this into your .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 500K
php_value post_max_size 500K
php_value max_execution_time 100
php_value max_input_time 100
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?